# Помогите распарсить файл в C#

Tags: c#

Есть файл с содержанием:

```
completed...
Database: localhost_students
+----------------------------+---------+
| Tabl                       |  Rows   |
+----------------------------+---------+
| faculty_data               |  2429   |
| address_data               |  1674   |
| scholarship_data           |  1460   |
+----------------------------+---------+
```

Цель выдернуть и скормить в массив/колекцию только эту часть данных без cмвола"|" с разделителями ",":

```
| faculty_data               |  2429   |
| address_data               |  1674   |
| scholarship_data           |  1460   |
```

Помогите пожалуйста составить правильную регулярку...

Comment: не нужна тут никакая регулярка: читайте строки, пока не встретите 2 раза свои `+----`, а потом читайте всё в массив, пока снова не будет строки состоящей из `+----`

Comment: а можно подробнее с примером?

Comment: @GeneratorSveta, параметры "faculty_data" и прочие - все с нижним подчеркиванием?

Comment: нет не все к сожаленью...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta, - ixSci правильно сказал.

Comment: это я понял сам копаю в эту сторону щас, пример был бы очень полезен так как привык тупо регулярками парсить подобное ,тока с такими видами данных встретился в первый раз...

Comment: не совсем понял какие строки в результате должны быть

Comment: вот эти строки:                                                                                               faculty_data,2429
address_data,1674
scholarship_data,1460

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Не стреляйте из пушки по воробьям, не нужны здесь регулярки

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Execute(string filename)
{
    var content = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var line in content)
    {
        var spl = line.Split('|');

        if (spl.Length == 4 && !string.Equals(spl[1].Trim(), "Tabl"))
            result.Add(spl[1].Trim(), spl[2].Trim());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Основа -- string.Split. Этот метод ещё проще, чем указанный @ixSci  - нет нужны искать начало фрагмента и конец, мы просто отбрасываем все строки, которые не имеют формата `| что-то | что-то ещё |`, дополнительно нужно лишь выкинуть шапку таблицы. Разумеется, мы при этом рассчитываем, что один файл содержит только одну таблицу - если не так, то нужно ловить начало-конец каждого фрагмента.

PS Опционально: `Dictionary<string, int>`, `List<string, int>` и т.п.

Comment: в основном одна таблица да но не редко бывают и по несколько подобных таблиц с разными БД в одном файле...

Answer (score 2):

Сильно не пинайтесь, некогда было делать с подсчетом вхождений, сделал с регуляркой просто чтобы помочь человеку:

```
        private void ParseText()
        {
            var list = File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "text.txt").Split('\n').ToList();
            var resultList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var line in list)
            {
                if (line.Contains("| ") && !line.Contains("+"))
                {
                    var temp = line.Replace(" | ", ",").Replace("|", "").Split(',');

                    if (new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$").IsMatch(temp[1].Trim()))
                    {
                        var resultLine = temp[0].Trim() + "," + temp[1].Trim();
                        if (!resultList.Contains(resultLine))
                            resultList.Add(resultLine);
                    }
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\r\n", resultList));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно так, просто и лаконично:

```
public TableInfo[] ParseTableInfo(string fileName)
{
    var content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

    var data = Regex.Matches(content, @"^\|\s*(?<tabl>[^\s|]+)\s*\|\s*(?<rows>\d+)\s*\|\r?$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => new
                    {
                        Table = m.Groups["tabl"].Value,
                        Rows = int.Parse(m.Groups["rows"].Value)
                    });

    return data.ToArray();
}
```

И потом использовать этот метод в коде:

```
var data = ParseTableInfo("<путь_к_файлу>");

foreach(var item in data)
    Console.WriteLine("Table {0} have {1} rows", item.Table, item.Row);
```

Сам тип `TableInfo` очень прост:

```
public class TableInfo
{
    public string Table { get; set; }
    public int Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Если файл большой (десятки МБ и больше), можно не грузить все в память разом методом `File.ReadAllText`, и не парсить все эти мегабайты единой операцией, а читать файл построчно, например - с помощью [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx), и парсить этой же регуляркой уже строки по отдельности. Только флаг `RegexOptions.Multiline` указывать уже не надо в этом случае.

По поводу парса имени таблицы небольшое замечание. Я не знаю, какие в данном случае возможны варианты именования, поэтому исходил из того, что вайтспейс или `|` будет означать окончание имени. Зная больше о возможных именованиях можно составить более подходящий парс имени таблицы.

Comment: а как обратится то правильно по группам? чет не могу вытащить данные из: "data" не как...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta Поменял немного ответ, что б внести больше ясности, заодно добавил и пример использования. Переменная `data` - это уже не результат регекса, а обычный тип с двумя своствами. Сделал тип не анонимным, вместо него теперь `TableInfo`. Так будет нагляднее,

Comment: @GeneratorSveta В целом же получение по группе происходит в методе `Select`: `m.Groups["tabl"].Value` и `m.Groups["rows"].Value`.